# Wait for the user mouse down event before continuing game loop

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have a game loop that re-draws a game board after each player makes a move. I would like to pause the main loop and wait until a player places a piece on the board, i.e. triggers a mouse down event on the canvas. Right now the game loop continues to redraw the board. Is there a way to wait for the player to move before continuing the loop?

```js
var initGameLoop = function() {
  player1 = new humanPlayer();
  player2 = new computerPlayer();
  while (gameState) {
    redraw();
    player1.acceptMove();
    redraw();
    player2.acceptMove();
  }
};

var humanPlayer = function() {
  this.acceptMove = function() {
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", addPieceWithMouse);
  };
};

var computerPlayer = function() {
  this.acceptMove = function() {
    computerMove();
  };
};
```

Comment: That `while` loop is suspicious, and probably what needs to change. Learn about asynchronous programming in JavaScript (callbacks, events, Promises…). It's too broad a topic to fit a StackOverflow answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows the desired effect using a continuous game loop.  It does not run the redraw while the gameState is `playerMove`.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var gameState = "normal";

var initGameLoop = function() {
  player1 = new humanPlayer();
  player2 = new computerPlayer();
  function animate () {
    if(gameState === "playerMove") {
      
    } else {
      player1.acceptMove();
      player2.acceptMove();
      redraw();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }
  animate()
};

function redraw() {
  ctx.font="10px Sans-serif";
  ctx.fillStyle="#333333";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle="#00FFFF";
  ctx.fillText(player1.count,100,50);
  ctx.fillStyle="#FFFF00";
  ctx.fillText(player2.count,100,70);
  ctx.fillStyle="#EEEEEE";
  ctx.fillText("PLAYER 1:", 40,50);
  ctx.fillText("PLAYER 2:", 40,70);
}

function addPieceWithMouse() {
   gameState = "playerMove"; 
}

function finishMove() {
   gameState = "normal";
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", addPieceWithMouse);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", finishMove);

var humanPlayer = function() {
  this.count = 0;
  this.acceptMove = function() {
    this.count += Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
  };
};

var computerPlayer = function() {
  this.count = 0;
  this.acceptMove = function() {
    this.computerMove();
  };
  this.computerMove = function() {
    this.count += Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  };
};


  
  initGameLoop();
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```